An Example of Flipping Contraction: the Contraction of Zero Sections of Vector Bundles?
Here is an example of flipping contraction:

Consider the projective space $\mathbb{P}^d$ with vector bundle $\mathscr{E}:=\mathscr{O}(-a_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathscr{O}(-a_r)$ for $a_i>0$. Consider the total space
$$X^+:=\underline{\mathbf{Spec}}_{\mathbb{P}^d}\bigoplus_{m\geq0}\mathrm{Sym}^m\mathscr{E}^{\vee}$$ Then by the surjection $H^0(\mathbb{P}^d,\mathrm{Sym}^m\mathscr{E}^{\vee})\otimes\mathscr{O}\to\mathrm{Sym}^m\mathscr{E}^{\vee}$ we get
$$X^+\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^d\times\mathrm{Spec}\bigoplus_{m\geq0}H^0(\mathbb{P}^d,\mathrm{Sym}^m\mathscr{E}^{\vee})\to \mathrm{Spec}\bigoplus_{m\geq0}H^0(\mathbb{P}^d,\mathrm{Sym}^m\mathscr{E}^{\vee})=:S.$$
Then this is a flipping contraction (when $r\geq 2$, for example) with exceptional locus is the zero section of $X^+$.

Note that as the zero section $Z$ is contracted to the closed subscheme defined by $\mathfrak{m}_p:=\bigoplus_{m>0}H^0(\mathbb{P}^d,\mathrm{Sym}^m\mathscr{E}^{\vee})$ which is a point $p\in S$. But how to show the locus out side $F$ is an isomorphism?
Now I have a geometric intuition about this: if you think of it as in $\mathbb{P}^d\times S$, then the fibers of $X^+$ will rotate around the zero section, so projecting onto $S$ is a contracting zero-section but isomorphic elsewhere. But I don't know how to write a detailed proof. Maybe we can consider the projective completion and use the base-point free linear system?
Moreover I think we can do this for any direct sum of anti-ample line bundles?

Thank you for your any help.
